# ASP.NET/SQL 2008 Performance issue

Tags: asp.net, database, optimization, orm, query-optimization

We've developed a system with a search screen that looks a little something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nsourceservices.com](http://demo1.nsourceservices.com/images/logos/stackoverflow1.png))</sub>

As you can see, there is some fairly serious search functionality. You can use any combination of statuses, channels, languages, campaign types, and then narrow it down by name and so on as well.

Then, once you've searched and the leads pop up at the bottom, you can sort the headers.

The query uses ROWNUM to do a paging scheme, so we only return something like 70 rows at a time.

**The Problem**

Even though we're only returning 70 rows, an awful lot of IO and sorting is going on. This makes sense of course.

This has always caused some minor spikes to the Disk Queue. It started slowing down more when we hit 3 million leads, and now that we're getting closer to 5, the Disk Queue pegs for up to a second or two straight sometimes.

That would actually still be workable, but this system has another area with a time-sensitive process, lets say for simplicity that it's a web service, that needs to serve up responses very quickly or it will cause a timeout on the other end. The Disk Queue spikes are causing that part to bog down, which is causing timeouts downstream. The end result is actually dropped phone calls in our automated VoiceXML-based IVR, and that's very bad for us.

**What We've Tried**

We've tried:

- Maintenance tasks that reduce the number of leads in the system to the bare minimum.
- Added the obvious indexes to help.
- Ran the index tuning wizard in profiler and applied most of its suggestions. One of them was going to more or less reproduce the entire table inside an index so I tweaked it by hand to do a bit less than that.
- Added more RAM to the server. It was a little low but now it always has something like 8 gigs idle, and the SQL server is configured to use no more than 8 gigs, however it never uses more than 2 or 3. I found that odd. Why isn't it just putting the whole table in RAM? It's only 5 million leads and there's plenty of room.
- Poured over query execution plans. I can see that at this point the indexes seem to be mostly doing their job -- about 90% of the work is happening during the sorting stage.
- Considered partitioning the Leads table out to a different physical drive, but we don't have the resources for that, and it seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

**In Closing...**

Part of me feels like the server should be able to handle this. Five million records is not so many given the power of that server, which is a decent quad core with 16 gigs of ram. However, I can see how the sorting part is causing millions of rows to be touched just to return a handful.

So what have you done in situations like this? My instinct is that we should maybe slash some functionality, but if there's a way to keep this intact that will save me a war with the business unit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you searching on GUIDs? What's your clustered index? Have you considered an SSD in the server? Are you doing wildcard searches? If so, you may need to index the varchars backwards and forwards

Comment: @Matthew PK: No GUIDs. The clustered index is just the primary key -- LeadID (int). As for a solid state drive... Well, throwing money at it needs to be my last ditch option. But it is on my mind. :)

Comment: What about returning the entire result set and paging on the client? As a user, I would rather wait an extra 2 seconds up front than wait every time I page.

Comment: Is the query built in dynamic SQl or is it a fixed query? Could be the query itself needs to be tuned not the indexes.

Comment: @Matthew PK: Hmm I hadn't actually considered that. The problem is that the entire result set could be up to millions of leads and in ASP.NET I believe that would have to go right into viewstate, unless I changed directions entirely and did it *actually* on the client with some kind of jQuery, or perhaps with something like Silverlight. It doesn't seem like it would work, but to be honest I haven't branched out into that kind of development yet. Do you think that's a legitimate option with millions of leads on the wire?

Comment: @HLGEM: Well, it is being built by an ORM. So it's a big paramaterized query. You could be right about that, maybe I should get the SQL it emits and post it.

Comment: @HLGEM: This may also be into the realm where an ORM just isn't the best option. Actully I probably am losing a ton of IO to the number of fields it pulls.

Comment: ORM can be dangerous if you assume it's optimizing your query. For a tricky, performance-hungry query you might consider using an sp (or even a pattern to decide on a specific sp depending on the search criteria). I think you are right about ASP and the viewstate... dumping a million rows there might not be the best option.

Comment: This may be too obvious... are you using the 64bit version of SQLServer?

Comment: @Matthew PK Searching on GUIDs won't cause these sorts of issues. I've got more records than that, all IDs are GUIDs, and it works just fine. Also, returning >2M records and sorting in JavaScript is a BAD, BAD idea. You may as well just use XML for your data store (blech).

Comment: @David, true but sort performance can be affected by the clustered index... in this case not really relevant.

Comment: @Matthew PK: Yep it's 64bit. I double-checked.

Comment: @Matthew PK: The ORM is indeed building an absurd query. I would post it here but it's 8k of solid text, lol. :) So that's where I will now focus my effort!

Comment: @Brian MacKay well in that case I'll add it as an answer :P

Comment: How about if you initiate another thread to start displaying the first N rows of the result set while the query continues searching the desired info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database bottlenecks can frequently be improved by improving your SQL queries. Without knowing what those look like, consider creating an operational data store or a data warehouse that you populate on a scheduled basis.

Sometimes flattening out your complex relational databases is the way to go. It can make queries run significantly faster, and make it a lot easier to optimize your queries, since the model is very flat. That may also make it easier to determine if you need to scale your database server up or out. A capacity and growth analysis may help to make that call.

Transactional/highly normalized databases are not usually as scalable as an ODS or data warehouse.

Edit: Your ORM may have optimizations as well that it may support, that may be worth looking into, rather than just looking into how to optimize the queries that it's sending to your database. Perhaps bypassing your ORM altogether for the reports could be one way to have full control over your queries in order to gain better performance.

Comment: Yet another place where ORMs fall flat on their face.

Comment: Yeah, an ORM is great for certain scenarios, perhaps not this. Perhaps what could work if the solution needs to stay ORM oriented could be a flattened database model, with a simple object layer to construct the queries with. I suspect that the path of least resistance may be to just look into ways to optimize the existing ORM queries

Answer (score 2):

1. determine which ad-hoc queries will most likely be run or limit the search criteria with stored procedures.. can you summarize data?.. treat this
   app like a data warehouse.
2. create indexes on each column involved in the search to avoid table scans.
3. create fragments on expressions.
4. periodically reorg the data and update statistics as more leads are loaded.
5. put the temporary files created by queries (result sets) in ramdisk.
6. consider migrating to a high-performance RDBMS engine like Informix OnLine.
7. Initiate another thread to start displaying N rows from the result set while the query
   continues to execute.

Comment: Good stuff...additionally, while you're not getting this error, the steps still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719841/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-timeout-expired#4719892

Comment: unless you are carefully controlling your queries (and I'm guessing the ORM isn't doing this) excessive indices may cause the DB to try a "jack of all trades" plan rather than selecting the "best" index for a given type of search.

Comment: This is really interesting, do you have a specific tool you use for building ramdisks? Google found RamDisk and RamDisk plus.

Comment: @Brian: RamDisk Plus 11.. you also have to consider how many simultaneous users will be performing queries. capacity planning will determine how many gigs of RAM your app will require.

Comment: @BrianMacKay: Would it be possible to initiate another thread to start displaying search results, even though the query has not yet completed building the result set?

Answer (score 2):

Consider how your ORM is creating the queries.
If you're having poor search performance perhaps you could try using stored procedures to return your results and, if necessary, multiple stored procedures specifically tailored to which search criteria are in use.